# Find empty/white space in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named 'contacts', it contains a column named 'mobile'. In the 'mobile' column some cells are empty. 
 
 
now, how can I find which rows contain empty space in 'mobile' column?

I have used this code,

```
select * from contacts where trim(mobile) is null;
```

But it gives no results.

Comment: try: `select * from contacts where mobile is null or   trim(mobile) = '';`

Comment: @oto-shavadze Thank you so much for ur cooperation. It works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select * from contacts where mobile is null or mobile=''
```

Comment: You shuold also add `OR TRIM(mobile) = ''`

Comment: Thank you so much for ur cooperation. It works.  @michal turczyn

Comment: @Prodiptukhor You should accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ifNull(mobile,'') = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express this using a single comparison:

```
select *
from contacts
where nullif(trim(mobile), '') is null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gordon . it works also. I did some edit.